# what is the meaning of this symbol $f_n(x)=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$?

Tags: real-analysis

what is the  meaning of this  symbol  $f_n(x)=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$on $[0,1]$?

I was trying to goolge it  but i didn't found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably $\chi$ is the characteristic function, so $$\chi_{[0,1/n]}(x):=\begin{cases}1 \qquad x\in[0,1/n] \\0 \qquad x\notin[0,1/n]\end{cases}$$ and then $f_n$ multiplies this by $n$.

Comment: Yup, since "characteristic" starts with $\chi$.  ^_^